# Django. Добавить метод в ModelAdmin fieldset

Tags: django

Не получается добавить метод в ModelAdmin fieldset.
Django 3.1.1
Python 3.6
Делаю так:

```
class ObjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'number')
    fieldsets = (('Area', {'fields': ('calc_area', )}), )
    readonly_fields = ('calc_area', )

    def calc_area(self, obj):
        return 100

    calc_area.short_description = 'Площадь'
    calc_area.allow_tags = 'True'
```

Получаю ошибку:
`django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (calc_area) specified for Object. Check fields/fieldsets/exclude attributes of class ObjectAdmin.`

Причём в list_display calc_area добавляется без проблем.

Answer (score 0):

в `list_fields` отображаются поля, которые формируются в ModelAdmin
`fieldsets` же отвечает уже за формировании формы, которая будет отображаться при редактировании. Соответственно поля там ты должен указывать поля, которые есть в классе `ModelForm` для редактирования этой модели.

если тебе нужно какое-то вычисляемое поле чисто для информации
Можно либо подправить html шаблон формы, что бы выводить нужную тебе информацию, либо сделать как-то так:

```
class ObjectEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
    calc_area = forms.CharField(label='вычисляемое поле', required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'disabled': 'disabled', 'readonly': True})
   
    class Meta:
        model = Object
        fields = ('calc_area', 'Field1', ..., )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['calc_area'].initial = 100
```

после того как ты в форме добавил вычисляемое поле, ты можешь использовать его в `fieldset`.
p.s.: не забудь добавить эту форму в `ModelAdmin`

```
class ObjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   form = ObjectEditForm
```